# Android json parsing in background without affecting activity performance

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity, android-background

I have to parse `Json` data and save it into a `Sqlite` database, I want to do it in the background so that it will not affect the activity performance.

My data and UI are not connected.

After parsing and saving the data into the `Sqlite` process should automatically stop.

Comment: Use AsyncTask and parse and save data in doinBackground().

Comment: Use threads, AsyncTask to work in background.

Comment: If the data and your UI are not connected,try using an [IntentService](http://www.developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

Comment: yes same i am using  droidekas

Comment: Then thats the best android can offer you  in this context :,if you really want to pursue further you could check out [BoltsFramework](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no real question asked here, I Will give an answer that seems suiting to your problem.

First you need to use [Asyntasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), then after you treated the response you should do something like getting the instance of your database and calling the right Insertion method by passing it your the JSONObject. If it's a JSONArray, then you should loop on the array calling that function (passing the object you're on in the loop).

You could also have an object that will parse your JSON into itself, then you could call the insert methode which suits to the object.

Comment: the asyntask will slow the activity .I don't want to affect UI performance of activity and till asynctask finish user will move to another activity and it will still running that will slow the app .

Comment: they're meant to do that kind of job, there's nothing faster than a threading solution, and you'l still be able to use the UI, so I can't see the problem with asynctask

Comment: should we use background service that will run separately and we can write our parsing and data saving  logic inside this service  ??

Comment: yes it is able to, and it should be used to. The only thing it needs is the application context to get the instance of your SQLite database

Comment: let's say obj is your JSON Object, you just need to parse it using obj.get[type]("Key");

Like obj.getInt("remoteDatabaseId");

Comment: that parsing and saving this all i know I just want the best way so that my UI  will not slow .as I experience asynctast slow the activity

Answer (score 2):

Try this it may help

```
private void createHandler() {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   // Do parsing here
                    handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                    Looper.myLooper().quit();
               }
            }, 20);

            Looper.loop();
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```